# Конечный автомат

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Набросал пример исходя из описания алгоритма. Хочу услышать замечания, что стоило бы изменить в этом коде:

```js
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_finite-state_machine
class FSM {
  constructor(transitions = []) {
    this.transitions = new Map();
    for (let {
        from,
        event,
        to,
        action
      } of transitions) {
      this.addTransition(from, event, to, action);
    }
    this.currentState = transitions.length ? transitions[0].from : null;
  }

  addTransition(from, event, to, action) {
    let events = this.transitions.get(from);
    if (!events) {
      events = new Map();
      this.transitions.set(from, events);
    }
    events.set(event, {
      to,
      action
    });
  }

  emit(event, ...args) {
    const events = this.transitions.get(this.currentState);
    if (events) {
      const obj = events.get(event);
      if (obj) {
        this.currentState = obj.to;
        obj.action.apply(this, args);
      }
    }
  }
}


const turnstile = new FSM([{
    from: 'locked',
    event: 'coin',
    to: 'unlocked',
    action: () => {
      console.log('Турникет разблокирован, и посетитель может пройти.');
    }
  },
  {
    from: 'locked',
    event: 'push',
    to: 'locked',
    action: () => {
      console.log('Посетитель толкает турникет, но тот заблокирован.');
    }
  },
  {
    from: 'unlocked',
    event: 'coin',
    to: 'unlocked',
    action: () => {
      console.log('Посетитель опускает еще одну монету в турникет, состояние не меняется.');
    }
  },
  {
    from: 'unlocked',
    event: 'push',
    to: 'locked',
    action: () => {
      console.log('Как только посетитель проходит, турникет блокируется.');
    }
  },
]);

turnstile.emit('push');
turnstile.emit('coin');
turnstile.emit('coin');
turnstile.emit('push');
turnstile.emit('push');
```

Вывод:

```
Посетитель толкает турникет, но тот заблокирован.
Турникет разблокирован, и посетитель может пройти.
Посетитель опускает еще одну монету в турникет, состояние не меняется.
Как только посетитель проходит, турникет блокируется.
Посетитель толкает турникет, но тот заблокирован.
```

Answer (score 1):

просто ещё один способ:

```js
class Au {
  constructor(States, Symbols, Table, currentState = States[Object.keys(States)[0]]) {
    this.States = States;
    this.Symbols = Symbols;
    this.Table = Table;
    this.currentState = currentState;
    ch(States, Symbols);
    info(States, Symbols, Table);
  }
  emit(_Symbol, ..._args) {
    let qqw = this.Table[this.currentState + _Symbol];
    let state = null;
    if (qqw) {
      if (qqw[0])
        this.currentState = qqw[0];
      if (qqw[1])
        qqw[1].apply(null, _args);
    }
  }
}

const turnstile = (function() {
  const States = {
    locked: 1 << 0,
    unlocked: 1 << 1,
  };
  const Symbols = {
    coin: 1 << 2,
    push: 1 << 3,
  };
  const Table = {
    [States.locked + Symbols.coin]: [States.unlocked, () => console.log('Турникет разблокирован, и посетитель может пройти.')],
    [States.locked + Symbols.push]: [States.locked, () => console.log('Посетитель толкает турникет, но тот заблокирован.')],
    [States.unlocked + Symbols.coin]: [States.unlocked, () => console.log('Посетитель опускает еще одну монету в турникет, состояние не меняется.')],
    [States.unlocked + Symbols.push]: [States.locked, () => console.log('Как только посетитель проходит, турникет блокируется.')],
  };
  return new Au(States, Symbols, Table);
})();

turnstile.emit(turnstile.Symbols.push);
turnstile.emit(turnstile.Symbols.coin);
turnstile.emit(turnstile.Symbols.coin);
turnstile.emit(turnstile.Symbols.push);
turnstile.emit(turnstile.Symbols.push);

// --

function ch(States, Symbols) {
  let a = Object.keys(States);
  let b = Object.keys(Symbols);
  let ch = new Set([...a, ...b]);
  if (ch.size !== (a.length + b.length)) {
    throw new Error('номера ключей States и Symbols совпадают');
  }
}

function info(States, Symbols, Table) {
  let l = {
    'количество возможных комбинаций': Object.keys(States).length * Object.keys(Symbols).length,
    'текущее количество комбинаций': Object.keys(Table).length,
  };
  Object.keys(l).forEach(_k => console.log(_k, l[_k]));
}
```

---

наверное, `this` не нужен

> obj.action.apply(this, args);

считаю что повторяющийся код, во избежании ошибок, должен быть в функции или классе

```
{
    from: 'locked',
    event: 'coin',
    to: 'unlocked',
    action: () => {
    console.log('Турникет разблокирован, и посетитель может пройти.');
    }
}
```